Efficient Data structure for searching substrings
I am trying to find a Data structure that saves strings and efficiently finds all strings that contain a given substring, e.g.:
data = ["abc", "ccc", "akro", "muhaca"] -> find("c") ->["abc, "ccc", "muhaca"]
class EfficientStructure {
      vector<string> find(const string & substr) const;
}

Thank you for all your help.
My only idea was to go through all the strings and use std::string.find(substr) to find if given string has a substring, but I would like to know if there is a faster solution.

Sounds like you may want an inverted index.

@JerryCoffin No not really my strings are small and I just need to check if they contain one substring. I do not need to search some huge document

Then you don't need to use anything beyond naive searching.

Okay, okay I know it is going to be still really fast I was just interested if something like this existed :)

Someone did, and you said your problem is too small to need it, what do you mean if they existed? Although granted, inverted index is probably the wrong tool.

In C++23 you can do it lazily without exessive copying of data: auto out_rng = in_rng | std::views::filter(std::bind_back(std::ranges::contains_subrange, pattern_str));.  Where in_rng is the source vector and pattern_str is the  substring to find. The overhead depends on what you do with the out_rng.

You will have to decide if you spend time at each search or once with an indexing.

At each search: the order of your data doesn't change anything. The container will depend on the way you fill your database. If you want unicity, std::set<std::string> is probably a good choice. The searching algorithm will be std::find(data.begin(), data.end(), [](std::string const& s){ return s.find(substr) != std::string::npos; })

You can build an index: a mapping between prefixes and lists of pointers of the strings containing this prefix. Then, in the seaching algorithm, you just have to serch in the strings having the prefix starting your substr.



If we talk about data structures, then you will need to build a tree. The specific choice depends on the situation and in general there is no “best” solution for any situation, so it’s up to you to do your research. From ready-made solutions, you can choose one of the basic algorithms, for example, KMP algorithm, Aho-Corasick algorithm, Boyer–Moore string-search algorithm

I think a suffix array is the top solution:
https://github.com/Tascate/Suffix-Arrays-in-CPP/blob/master/Skew.cpp
